# What does the vmx parameter "mks.keyboardFilter = allow" do?

Tags: windows, vmware-workstation

I have a Windows software that can move the mouse cursor via keyboard arrow keys. This works well in a non-VM environment. However in a VM environment, the mouse cursor goes back to its previous position when moving it via the keyboard. The cursor moves a pixel or so and then quickly reverts back to its original position. I found out that this behaviour is caused by the **mks.keyboardFilter = allow** parameter. If I remove that line from the vmx file, the software works fine.

Does anyone know what **mks.keyboardFilter** is for? There seems to be scant information regarding vmx parameters and the reference at [sanbarrow.com](http://www.sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-advanced.html#mks) does not say anything.

Environment:
VMware Workstation 7.1.0 build-261024
Guest OS: Windows XP SP3 (also reproduced with Windows 7)
Host OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question...

I still do not know the full extent of what **mks.keyboardFilter = "allow"** does. But it swallows/resets mouse cursor movement if it was done via the keyboard arrow keys. In a Windows XP SP3 guest, MouseKeys (i.e. Control Panel -> Accessibility Options -> Mouse -> Use MouseKeys) only works if that line is not present in the .vmx file.

Answer (score 0):

[THIS](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007178) is the best description of what it's there for - basically it's a virtual keyboard driver enable/disable switch.

Comment: I've seen that. It seems to me though that deselecting the enhanced virtual keyboard and adding the mks.keyboardFilter line are separate steps. So it's not simply a switch for the virtual driver.

Comment: Also when I removed that line, the keyboard still worked in the guest OS.

Comment: The link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

I think at least one use of the keyboard filter driver is to allow Ctrl+Alt+Del to be captured by the VM.